# How can I use 'say' with Perl 5.8.8?

Tags: perl, file, bash, search

I'm assigned to a project (PHP/MySQL) that needs some review and possibly fixes.

As a part of it it is planned to check correctness of all variables that we get via GET and POST. We have a bunch of PHP (*.php*) and [Smarty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smarty_(template_engine)) (*.tpl*) files that have several thousands of lines of code all together, so it would be painful to search for all $_GET[...] and $_POST[...] references manually. So I tried doing this:

```
find . -name "*.php" -or -name "*.tpl" |
xargs perl -ne 'use feature say; say $1 while m/(\$_(GET|POST)\[[\s]*[\S]+[\s]*\])/g;' |
sort -u
```

Basically it creates a list of all $_GET[...] and $_POST[...] references in the project, and then deletes the repeated values from it. But it didn't work, because I have Perl 5.8.8 on my development machine, which does not support 5.10+ feature 'say', and our system administrator said that upgrade is undesired. I'm not sure why, but he's the boss.

So, is there a way to replace 'say' with some other code, or maybe even replace Perl with another tool?

Comment: You could use egrep instead of perl.

Comment: Why *do* the systems administrators always say that?

Comment: @TLP : It usually has something to do with the fragility of the sysadmin ecosystem, but don't tell anyone I said so ;)

Comment: @TLP : The two may overlap, yes :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perl 5.10 added 'say', which is a substitute for 'print', that automatically adds a newline to the output. Hence you can write

```
say "hello";
```

...instead of having to write:

```
print "hello\n";
```

Simply drop the 'use feature say;' and replace 'say $1' with:

```
print "$1\n";
```

Answer (score 13):

Don't forget that it's very easy to emulate `say`:

```
sub say { print @_, "\n" }
```

Just add it to the beginning of the Perl code and use as you normally would.

Answer (score 7):

The `-l` option without octal adds a newline to the end of print statements. From [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-l*%5B_octnum_%5D):

> enables automatic line-ending processing. It has two separate effects.
> First, it automatically chomps $/ (the input record separator) when
> used with -n or -p. Second, it assigns $\ (the output record
> separator) to have the value of octnum so that any print statements
> will have that separator added back on. **If octnum is omitted, sets $
>
> to the current value of $/** .

So...

```
perl -lne ... print $1 ...
```

will replace `say`.

Answer (score 3):

> But it didn't work because I have perl 5.8.8 on my development machine, which does not support 5.10+ feature 'say',

Perl 5.8.8 was released on Jan 31, 2006.  Since then, we've seen 5.10, 5.10.1, 5.12, 5.12.1, 5.12.2, 5.12.3, 5.12.4, 5.14, 5.14.1, 5.14.2, ... and I might be out of date.  Three major revisions (5.10, 5.12, 5.14) with fixes each, since 5.8.8 came out.  Deprecation cycles have occurred, and you've not had a chance to experience them to help clean up your code.

The simple solution is to upgrade.

> and our system administrator said that upgrade is undesired. I'm not sure why, but

And, so?  It's not like he's the boss of ...

> he's the boss.

Oh.

Well, I'm not one that is well known for listening to bosses when they're being silly or plain incorrect.  Then again, I never advocate doing what I do :-)

If your boss is concerned with upgrading the system perl, he's right. That's undesirable. (I suggest getting a newer distro, but if you're on AIX, you're stuck as newer AIX's still ship that old level of perl.)  But there's no reason why you have to upgrade the system perl just to upgrade perl.

You can have more than one perl installed.  As long as you don't touch /usr/bin/perl, and you shouldn't as that should be the system perl at all times, you should be fine.  I have installed perls 5.8.8, 5.10.1, 5.12.0, 5.12.1, 5.12.2, 5.14.0, 5.14.1, and 5.14.2 all in ~/perl/$version, created symlinks in ~/bin for each one (e.g., perl5.8.8 is a symlink to the 5.8.8 perl binary), and now I can use *development* perls for their new features while still being able to test on older perls when necessary.  And, because I'm installing to my own home directory, I don't need sysadmin access.  If you're not on Linux, you *will* need a compiler.  (Even on Linux you may need some development packages installed, e.g., on SLES we often need to install -devel RPMs to get extra modules to compile.)  But this is likely a lower bar to meet for your sysadmin than overwriting the system perl (which he's right to warn against).

Comment: And there is [perlbrew](http://www.perlbrew.pl/) which is designed to let you easily switch among various versions while leaving the vendor-supplied version unadulterated.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to emulate `say` in perl 5.8 is to use as follows:

```perl
sub say { print @_?@_:$_, "\n" }
```

It allows for many scenerios like

```perl
say 'hi';
say for ('hello', 'world');
say for 0..9;
```

will generate

```
hi
hello
world
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```